# Angular JS ng file upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, ng-file-upload

i'm using Angular's JS well known ng file upload directive (https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) in a project i'm working on, but i'm having an issues regarding validations. I added the ngf-pattern directive, in order to prevent users from uploading certain file formats. This works well, and each invalid file is available in the $invalidFiles array. Is there anyway to clear this array?

I am using $invalidFiles array in order to detect when invalid file was used, and alert the user. The file is not displayed in the UI, and not added to my model, but still I cannot submit the form because the form is invalid. only after I add a valid file I can submit the form. Is there a way to detect invalid files but still be able to submit the form ?

Hope I was clear.. Thanks!

Comment: can we have a Fiddle for your scenario ?

Comment: yes! you can find it here: http://jsfiddle.net/2vq88rfs/631/ . if you add invalid file it won't be added to the model, it will be added to the error files array and the form will be invalid until a valid file will be added. I just want to be able to catch the error, but still submit the form (if before some valid files were already added). hope it helps..

Comment: @tsahnar if you want to submit an invalid form then what is the point of knowing if the form is valid or not?

Comment: @Akis_Tfs Have you selected proper user for your comment ?

Comment: @Sampath i am really sorry, wrong tag

Comment: @Akis_Tfs Heheheee... No problem :D

Comment: @Akis_Tfs In my form I have other fields beside the file field, that is why I check if the form is valid or not. Anyway the allowInvalid option does the trick! thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the thing you really need is `ngf-change` rather then `ngf-select`. Based on the documentation, the handler function you assign to ngf-change directive would be called whenever you select, drop, or cleared.

If the only thing you want to achieve is to allow form submission regardless it's valid or invalid, another approach would be leveraged on `ng-model-options`. There is an option called `allowInvalid`, by default it's `false`, set it to `true` would do the trick.

So in your example:

```
<button name="bla" multiple accept="image/*"              
        ngf-keep="true" 
        ng-model="myFiles" 
        ngf-pattern="'image/*'" 
        ngf-max-size="1MB"
        ngf-change="handleFiles($files, $invalidFiles)"
        ngf-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}">
  Select Files
</button>
```

Notice the last two directives we have changed here.

For full reference, you may check the official document at the section of [Full reference - File select and drop](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: @tsahnar no worry, feel free to vote it up if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need : [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sampath_lokuge/2vq88rfs/633/)

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    alert('form is ready');
   }
```

Comment: now you removed the condition that checks if the form is valid or not., so it misses the whole point

Comment: You can still catch the errors and also form can be submitted no ? If not what do you need ?